# How to sort huge data in spring data mongodb

Tags: sorting, pagination, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection that contains lots of document(about 10 million).How can i sort these documents without using aggregation framework ?

Here i want to use like this code :

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber, howMany, sort);
                query.with(pageable);
```